# Validating RDF files using Raptor or Sax

Tags: python, validation, rdf, sax, redland

Given a RDF file, I want to write a python script to validate the file and comment if in wrong format. HOw do I do this with RAptor? or Sax or is there any other library? No luck with w3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options with raptor:

**Option 1:** Use the `rapper` command line, this is super fast. The function below is an example in python to wrap up the command. The `-c` option is to just count the number of triples. The parameter `lang` is just an option to specify the RDF format ntriples, rdfxml, turtle, ... The function checks the return code and throws an exception in case anything went wrong.

```
def rapper_count(f,lang):
    p=subprocess.Popen(["rapper","-i",lang,"-c",f],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, err = p.communicate()
    ret = p.poll()
    if ret <> 0:
        raise Exception, "Error parsing with rapper\n%s"%err
    return int(err.split()[-2])
```

**Option 2:** Use the redland [Python language bindings](http://librdf.org/docs/python.html). Something like the following would work:

```
import RDF

test_file = "/some/file"

uri=RDF.Uri(string="file:"+test_file)

parser=RDF.Parser(name="turtle")
if parser is None:
  raise Exception("Failed to create RDF.Parser raptor")

count=0
for s in parser.parse_as_stream(uri,uri):
  count=count+1

print "Parsing added",count,"statements"
```

This code has been extracted from [example.py](https://github.com/dajobe/redland-bindings/blob/master/python/example.py), check it out and you'll see more examples.

Comment: I dont really understand what you are doing in the subprocess. Can you elaborate manuel?

Comment: subprocess is a python routine to run commands. Basically I am calling the rapper utility. It is like if I was running `rapper -c -i rdfxml some_file` in my code. The functions tests for the return code and if it is not 0 then throws an Exception. Normally rapper returns some value, not 0, when the parsing is not valid.